# How to locate web elements by XPath in Selenium WebDriver using JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried to locate a web element of this page by the XPath but I don't know how. I use Selenium for the first time.

```
<h2>Newsletter</h2>
   <form action="" method="post" name="subscribe"><label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input class="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name..." />
      <label for="email">Email: </label> <input class="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" />
      <input class="btn btn-large" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
   </form>
   <a title="first link" href="#link1">First Link</a>
   <a title="second link" href="#link2">Second Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: did not mentioned which element you locating. There are many tags and elements which you want to locate using xpath?  seems your question is incomplete

Comment: Update the question with the element you are trying to locate along with your _code trials_

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate the element based on XPATH you should use the browser inspector. Select the target element, right click and select COPY XPATH.

[image]

After you can use selenium WebDriver selection by XPATH

Answer (score 0):

You can use FireBug,Firepath to locate element and get xpath and or directly use browser inspect. You can use relative x-path or Dynamic x-path.